# JSON not stopping form submit on modal window

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-window

I have a mvc project. I open a form in a modal dialog. The user fills in form and hits save. The form posts to the controller however I am trying to intercept and post via json.

Looking in Dev tools network section as well as having alert() in my json it is not running and I am thinking it is not attached properly? I have read several pages and it seems my json is basically correct.

I know there is a relation between the parent page and a window...which is a div that becomes the modal window. However I don't know enough to determine if this is part of the break down.

In the parent window here is how my modal is launched.

```
$("#edit").click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var detailsWindow = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");

        if (!detailsWindow)
        {
            // create a new window, if there is none on the page
            detailsWindow = $("#window")
                // set its content to 'loading...' until the partial is loaded
                .html("Loading...")
                .kendoWindow(
                    {
                        modal: true,
                        width: "800px",
                        height: "400px",
                        title: "@T("....")",
                        actions: ["Close"],
                        content:
                            {
                                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("...", "..."))",
                                data: { ... }
                            }
                    }).data('kendoWindow').center();
        }

        detailsWindow.open();

        });
```

The above code hits the controller and populates the model then loads the partial in centered modal as expected.

In the modal partial I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formCreateEdit" }))
{ 
   ...HTML ELEMENTS...
   <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="@T("...")" />
}

<script>
   $(function()
   {
     $("#formCreateEdit").submit
        (function (e)
        {
            alert(e);
            e.preventDefault(); //As we will manually submit the form
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("...", "..."))",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //here we check if database called resulted in Success/Failure
                    if (data.Result === "Success")
                    {
                        alert('Finis');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Show error message or whatever.
                    }
                }
            })
            //});
        });

</script>
```

---

**Edit:**

I have also tried intercepting the button click event. I may veru well have been doing it wrong so here is the code when I tried that:

```
$('#save').click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    // take over and perform ajax post

    alert('ddd');

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("...", "..."))",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data)
        {
            //here we check if database called resulted in Success/Failure
            if (data.Result === "Success")
            {
                alert('Finis');
            }
            else
            {
                //Show error message or whatever.
            }
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it ended up being more complicated because the modal is loaded from a view after passing through the controller...thus it is considered dynamically generated. So the solution was to attach the event handler post document generation as seen here. I have linked to these two post so that the SO members who have shared their knowledge with me can get upvotes if it benefits you as well.

[First Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442250/bound-event-handler-not-firing-modal-dialog-button-click?noredirect=1#comment41534041_26442250)

[Second Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510999/difficulty-attaching-event-handler-to-dynamically-generated-modal-window-element)

Answer (score 0):

Intercept the click of the submit button and not on the form.

```
$('#save').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   // take over and perform ajax post
})
```

Comment: I tried that...perhaps incorrectly. It goes straight to the controller as well. Check my edit.